# Simple Polymer element from web server works in Chrome but not Firefox or Safari or IE

Tags: firefox, polymer

I am working with serving a simple polymer element from a Tomcat server. The element works fine in Chrome but fails in the recent version of Firefox 49.0.2. 
I have attached the content the two elements and the problem seems to happen because the WebComponentsReady event is fired repeatedly over and over again in Firefox but in Chrome only four times.

Furthermore by including a include on the paper-slider element in the simple-element below causes Firefox to go into a loop where it keeps reloading the files over and over again ?!

```html
<link rel="import" href="./bower_components/paper-slider/paper-slider.html">
```

What is going on?

simple-element-demo.html (below)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Demo of simple element">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script>
  </script>
  <script src="./bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="import" href="./bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="./simple-element.html"></link>
</head>

<body>
  <div>Hello! I am going to demo simple-element. See below me.</div>
  <simple-element></simple-element>
</body>
<script>
  document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function(e) {
    console.log('WebComponentsReady', e);
    debugger;
  });
</script>

</html>
```

simple-element.html below

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Element</title>
  <script src="./bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="import" href="./bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="./bower_components/paper-slider/paper-slider.html">
</head>

<body>
  <dom-module id="simple-element">
    <template>
      <div class="container flex-horizontal">
        Hi There! I am Simple Element.
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'simple-element',
        properties: {
          prop1: {
            type: String,
            notify: true
          },
        },

        created: function() {
          console.log('Simple is created');
        },

        ready: function() {
          console.log('Simple is ready');
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by including webcomponents-lite.js **only once** in the main file: simple-element-demo.html.

I removed the line below from the simple-element.html and now it works just fine in all browsers.

```html
<script src="./bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js">
</script>
```